# Tensor product over several modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $M,N,P$ be both $R$ modules, where $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$.
How could one show $$M\otimes N\otimes P\cong (M\otimes N)\otimes P$$
where the left hand side is defined by trilinear maps. 
What I am thinking is to construct a linear map and its inverse. Define: $\varphi: M\otimes N\otimes P\rightarrow (M\otimes N)\otimes P:m\otimes n\otimes p\mapsto (m\otimes n)\otimes p$. This is well defined by the universal property.
What seems natural to me is to define its inverse as $\phi: (m\otimes n)\otimes p\mapsto m\otimes n\otimes p$. But how could one show the well definedness of this map?

Comment: Another way to show this is to show $(M\otimes N)\otimes P$ satisfies the trilinear universal property.

Answer (score 1):

For each $p \in P$, the map
\begin{align}
M \times N &\to M \otimes N \otimes P \\
(m,n) & \mapsto  m \otimes n \otimes p
\end{align}
is bilinear, and so there is a unique linear map
$$
f_p \colon M \otimes N \to M \otimes N \otimes P
$$
such that $f_p(m \otimes n) = m \otimes n \otimes p$ for all $m \in M$ and $n \in N$.

The uniqueness allows us to prove that $f_{rp_1+p_2} = rf_{p_1}+f_{p_2}$ for all $p_1,p_2 \in P$ and $r \in R$.

Hence, the map
\begin{align}
(M \otimes N) \times P &\to M \otimes N \otimes P \\
(t,p) & \mapsto  f_p(t)
\end{align}
is bilinear, so that there is a linear map
$$
\phi \colon (M \otimes N) \otimes P \to M \otimes N \otimes P
$$
such that $\phi(t \otimes p) = f_p(t)$ for all $t \in M \otimes N$ and $p \in P$.
In particular:
$$
\phi((m \otimes n) \otimes p) = f_p(m \otimes n) = m \otimes n \otimes p.
$$